# Is it possible to run multiple mongodb processes/servers/ports on one physical server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, production, staging

I have a `production` and `staging` environments on one machine. One rails app works the fulltime. One (actually the same) rails app is only for testing/implementing new features.

So I use a mongodb:

```
mongod --dbpath /path/to/my/production/rails/app/db
```

I would also like to run one mongod with:

```
mongod --dbpath /path/to/my/staging/rails/app/db
```

But I cannot imagine how to do that, because if I do just as described, I obviously get:

```
Mon Oct 14 16:12:59 [initandlisten] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:98 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
Mon Oct 14 16:12:59 [initandlisten] ERROR:   addr already in use
```

So what is the best practice to work with two different mongodb instances on one machine to be able to work with both production and staging apps separately?

## Update:

of course it is better to define different environments within the rails app (e.g. mongodb.yml) and use the same mongod process and port, but would be interesting if it is possible something like this (to compleetely separate environments):

```
port 27017 <--> --dbpath /path/to/my/production/rails/app/db
port 27018 <--> --dbpath /path/to/my/staging/rails/app/db
```

Comment: Note that we got a whole sister-site http://dba.stackexchange.com especially for administrating databases. So when you have any more questions which are not about programming for MongoDB but rather about administrating and configuring it, you might get a more competent answer there.

Comment: thanks for the point! I didn't visit this site before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

```
mongod --dbpath /path/to/my/production/rails/app/db --port 12345
mongod --dbpath /path/to/my/staging/rails/app/db --port 12346
```

Check out this earlier answer for more information/pitfalls: [multiple instances of Mongo DB on same server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15124610/multiple-instances-of-mongo-db-on-same-server)

Comment: You can also run full replicaSets on the same machine for testing :)

Answer (score 0):

Slightly modified version of my answer in the related question:

The aforementioned [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19362869/2505920) is not a recommended way to run multiple instances (especially when the servers might be running at the same time) as it will lead to usage of the same config parameters like for example *logpath* and *pidfilepath* which in most cases is not what you want.

Please, consider creating dedicated mongod configuration files like *mongod-PROD.conf* and *mongod-STAGE.conf*. In these files you may want to provide *dbpath*, *logpath* folders, *bind_ip*, *port* and *pidfilepath* specific to each mongod instance and that will not affect each other.

After these steps you are good to trigger two instances as follows

```
mongod --config <path-to>/mongod-PROD.conf
mongod --config <path-to>/mongod-STAGE.conf
```

You can find more details on mongodb docs [page](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/configuration/#run-time-database-configuration)